# How to convert two m3u8 file to mp4?

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg, converters

I want to convert two files .m3u8 ( one of it is audio and second is video) to .mp4 using ffmeg.
I tried that command:
`"ffmpeg.exe" -i "video.m3u8" -i "audio.m3u8" -acodec copy -vcodec copy -f mp4 video.mp4` but got an error:

> Invalid data found when processing input

I tried to play each of m3u8 files in vlc media player, so it is playable. 
Please help me!

Comment: If VLC can open them, why not use VLC to transcode them? (And just because VLC can play them doesn't mean they don't have invalid data; VLC may just be overlooking the invalid data)

Comment: Either your `video.m3u8` or `audio.m3u8` is giving wrong data instead of the expected usual. Did you check if the .m3u8 playlist content has correct formatting? Check by opening file in some text editor (like Notepad if on Windows OS).